# Threaded script exits prematurely

Tags: multithreading, perl

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
my $sema = Thread::Semaphore->new(8);

while(@compsCopy)
{
  my $thread1 = threads->create('Build', (shift @compsCopy), "clean");
}

sub FfsBuild {

    $sema->down();

    my ($comp, $action) = @_;

    my $cmd = "$MAKE $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH/$comp $action";
    my $retCode = system($cmd);
    push(@retCodes, $retCode);

    print "\n\t\t**** ERROR IN $comp ****\n" unless $retCode == 0;
    print "added proc $comp\n";    

    $sema->up();
    return $retCode;
}
```

This seems to work fine for the first 10-20 directories... but eventually I get:

```
Perl exited with active threads:
        364 running and unjoined
        14 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached

C:\dev>make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir0'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir1'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir2'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir3'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir4'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir5'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir6'
make: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/C/dev/dir7'
```

Where am I messing up here?

Comment: You probably need to join all of the threads from the "main" thread to make sure everything runs to completion.  Many runtimes exit when the main thread exits.

Comment: I'm confused how there are 364 running, when my semaphore is capped at 8 though?

Comment: @MrDuk “running” does not mean “executing at this moment” but “have been started, and haven't terminated yet”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't wait for you your threads to finish. Adding the following at the bottom will do the trick:

```
$_->join for threads->list;
```

---

You shouldn't create 378 threads then make it so only 8 execute at a time! What a waste! It's people running code like that that say Perl threads are inefficient. Create a pool of workers and assign the work to them.

```
use constant NUM_WORKERS => 8;

use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

sub worker {
    my ($job) = @_;
    FfsBuild($job, 'clean');
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue()) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
   }

   $q->enqueue($_) for @compsCopy;

   # When you're done adding to the queue.
   $q->end();
   $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

`FfsBuild` is what you had without the semaphore.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on the flow here - do you mind to elaborate on what is happening when with the Queue and the `async` call?

Comment: 1. `async BLOCK;` is short for `thread->create(sub BLOCK);`. The loop creates eight workers.

Comment: 2. The queue dispatches jobs to the workers. The workers grab a job from the queue (blocking until something is placed in the queue if necessary) until undef is returned (which happens when the queue is empty and ended).

Comment: 3. In this case, the work is the elements of @compsCopy, but it can be anything. By queueing array refs, you can pass arguments. e.g. `$q->enqueue([ 'job_type', @data ])`

Comment: Very neat! So, how can I reuse `q`? For example if I wanted to traverse another `@compsCopy` with a different action (e.g., 'l1' instead of 'clean')

Comment: Yes; I guess my question becomes, is the above faster than using semaphores, and specifying a limit? I assume this is allowing the OS to allocate threads appropriately?

Comment: Does the same thing but creates 300 fewer threads in the process. Yeah, I think it's faster. // I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant by the 2nd part is that instead of my saying "you're allowed to do this up to semaphore(8) times" this allows the OS to handle how it releases threads for execution?

Comment: That's still not clear. There's a question mark, but it's not preceded by a question! ||| Both Thread::Semaphore and Thread::Queue use threads::shared's `cond_wait`. (Everything does.) Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Threading with Perl is a bit difficult (and also rather inefficient. Don't do it without a good reason).

Every thread except the main thread either has to be `join`ed prior to exit, or be `detach`ed. You should still make sure that the thread terminates before you exit the process.

So something like `threads->create(...)->detach` should work here, but I think it's better to join:

```
my @threads;
for my $job (@jobs) {
    push @threads, threads->create(\&worker, $job);
}

# wait until all have completed
$_->join for @threads;
```

However, you will probably want to kick of a few workers at the start of the program, and feed them jobs via a `Thread::Queue` instead – each thread is a complete clone of the current interpreter state, which tends to use unnecessary large amounts of memory. Running hundreds of Perl threads is not likely to be useful.

Comment: `->detach` will just silence the fact that the threads didn't complete. Bad!